# Simplifying a Sum() across dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run the query below, the temp_08.members table created only features one column (Q4'10) which is the sum of all calcs.  This is incorrect.

INSTEAD I am trying to create a separate column for each quarter with the sum(calc) for just data inside that quarter.  For some reason the query below does not accomplish this.

Second, is there a more efficient way to write this query.  I will have 20 quarters, and the only thing that changes in each is the column name (as Q4_16) and the dates for each select.

```
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q4_10,
brand
into   temp_08.members
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '09/30/2010' and date <= '12/31/2010'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q1_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '12/31/2010' and date <= '3/31/2011'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q2_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '3/31/2011' and date <= '6/30/2011'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q3_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '6/30/2011' and date <= '9/30/2011'
GROUP BY brand

insert into temp_08.members
SELECT
sum(calc) as Q4_11,
brand
from temp_08.source
WHERE    date > '9/30/2011' and date <= '12/31/2011'
GROUP BY brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('quarter', date) as yyyyqq, brand, sum(calc) as sumcals,
INTO temp_08.members
FROM temp_08.source
GROUP BY date_trunc('quarter', date), brand;
```

You can do something like this for all the tables you want to create.  Note that the time period is an explicit column.

Comment: Gordon .. i think the op might be looking for a `pivot` too.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  The problem here is each query has a unique date range for quarter - think fiscal quarters for companies.  I need to be able to preserve the ability to custom define the start and end date for each quarter.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . The code is your question is using standard definitions for quarters.  However, it is not particularly hard to modify the code to handle other definitions.  That would be *another* question, though, not this one.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . No.  I am more inclined to *DELETE* my answer and to avoid answering your questions in the future.  Changing the question after it has a valid answer is very rude.  It can draw downvotes.  I would suggest that you roll back your edits to this question and ask another question.

Comment: Hi Gordon.  One follow up on this one.  I got the following error when implementing the above code: [42883] ERROR: function trunc("unknown", date) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC.